# Metabox saves on Update or Publish, but not on Saving Draft

Tags: metabox, save-post

I have created custom post types that also have custom meta_boxes I've created.  Currently, they save when I publish or update a post, but they don't save when I'm in draft mode making changes.

```
add_action('save_post', 'save_details');

function save_details(){
if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
    return $post_id;
}
global $post;
if ($post->post_type == 'events') { // Check to see if Event Type.
    update_post_meta($post->ID, "event_featuring", $_POST["event_featuring"]);
    update_post_meta($post->ID, "event_time", $_POST["event_time"]);
    update_post_meta($post->ID, "event_date", $_POST["event_date"]);
    update_post_meta($post->ID, "event_end_date", $_POST["event_end_date"]);
    update_post_meta($post->ID, "event_location", $_POST["event_location"]);
    update_post_meta($post->ID, "empid", $_POST["empid"]);
    update_post_meta($post->ID, "bhs_event", $_POST["bhs_event"]);
}
}
```

I tried using wp_insert_post_data instead of save_post, but then I had the opposite problem.  It would save on Drafts, but publishing the post no longer worked.  What do I need to do differently so I can update a draft (before publishing) and it will save?

Answer (score 1):

So you first tried hooking on to `wp_insert_post_data` and could save the meta data when saving Drafts but not when publishing.  Then you tried hooking on to `save_post` and could save meta data when publishing but not when saving Drafts.

The easiest solution would be to hook on to both.

```
add_action('save_post', 'save_details');
add_action('wp_insert_post_data', 'save_details');
```

---

## Edit

Both `save_post` and `wp_insert_post_data` are called at the same time and pass two parameters to callback functions.  In the source, it looks like this:

```
do_action('save_post', $post_ID, $post);
do_action('wp_insert_post', $post_ID, $post);
```

Bbut your function isn't accepting any parameters.  This will make `return $post_ID` fail and will likely cause other issues as well.

You should have:

```
function save_details( $post_ID, $post ) {
    ...
}
```

And your hook should be:

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_details', 10, 2 );
```

This will pass both `$post_ID` and `$post` into your function and *should* make things run a bit more smoothly.

Comment: Yeah, that would make sense but with both it acts like it did with just wp_insert_post_data.  It saves it, but won't publish.

Comment: Please see my revision.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm still having the same issue even with those changes.  In fact, I'm not even able to get it to publish.  It works fine (as posted above) when I publish or update a post.  It just will not save those fields when I'm working within a draft.

Comment: With all of that said, everything you wrote above certainly makes sense and I appreciate the help. For some reason though, it isn't working.

Comment: Something else is probably going on ... but without seeing the full code I can't really diagnose it.  And since this isn't a fix-my-specific-site-issue forum, you'd probably have better luck with deep troubleshooting over in the [support forums](http://wordpress.org/support).

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar problem which I think was triggered by upgrading wordpress to 3.1 although I did not get a chance to revert back to verify. I changed my code to pass in the $post_id and $post as above taking care to pass parameter 1,2 rather than 10, 2 as above and this fixed the problem. adding a hook to wp_insert_post did not work for me and gave me errors when adding a new custom post.

Hope this help. My first response so sorry if I'm unclear.

Comment: You may have the answer but this is not very clear, as you suspected. Can you provide, or recreate, the code that worked for you?